# How to schedule a camel route to start at specific time and run once in a day

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to poll a directory at a specific time each day. Right now I am using timer component with period=86400000 to run periodically every 24 hrs. But I wanted to start the route at a specific time and run for only weekdays mon-fri and not on weekends. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the camel-quartz2 component for this.

**From Camel Docs:**

> USING CRON TRIGGERS Quartz supports Cron-like expressions for
>   specifying timers in a handy format. You can use these expressions in
>   the cron URI parameter; though to preserve valid URI encoding we allow
>   + to be used instead of spaces.
>
> For example, the following will fire a message every five minutes
>   starting at 12pm (noon) to 6pm on weekdays:
>
> `from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0/5+12-18+?+*+MON-FRI")
>       .to("activemq:Totally.Rocks");`
>    which is equivalent to using the cron expression
>
> 0 0/5 12-18 ? * MON-FRI

You can get more usages of the cron scheduler at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html